# Two forms in one view Django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-views

I'm  a beginner in django and I want to put two diferent registers in the same view. But also I want to make my own forms and put diferent url at the action tag. I did it in one form, but when I puy the second form, this doesn't work.

This is my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class userProfile(models.Model):
    usermail = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    userpass = models.CharField(max_length=264)

class companyProfile(models.Model):
    companymail = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    companyname = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    companypass = models.CharField(max_length=264)
```

This is my `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from Pruebas_app.models import companyProfile, userProfile

class registerCompany(forms.Form):
    companypassconf = forms.CharField()
    class Meta():
        model = companyProfile
        fields = ['companymail','companyname', 'companypass']
        labels = {'companymail': '', 'companyname': '', }
        widgets = { 'companypass': forms.PasswordInput(),}

class registerUser(forms.Form):
    userpassconf = forms.CharField()
    class Meta():
        model = companyProfile
        fields = ['usermail','username', 'userpass']
        labels = {'usermail': '', 'username': '', }
        widgets = {'userpass': forms.PasswordInput(),}
```

And this is my `template`:

```
<form action="{ url 'user_register'}" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="email" name="usermail">
  <input type="password" name="userpass">
  <input type="password" name="userpassconf">
  <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
<form action="{ url 'company_register'}" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="companyname">
  <input type="email" name="companymail">
  <input type="password" name="companypass">
  <input type="password" name="companypassconf">
  <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

And this is my `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Pruebas import forms
from Pruebas.forms import registerCompany, registerUser
from django.http import HttpResponse

def user_register(request):
    form = forms.registerUser()
    regd = False
    passmatch = True
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = registerUser(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_data = form.cleaned_data
            print (form_data.get("userpass"))
            if form_data.get("userpass") == form_data.get("userpassconf"):
                passmatch = True
                form.save()
                regd = True
                print("saved")
            else:
                passmatch = False
        else:
            print("error")
            red = 'Pruebas/register.html'
            regd = False
    return render(request, 'Pruebas/register.html', {'registered': regd, "matchPass": passmatch})
```

I tried to send the data from my forms to one unique view, but I only can recive the data from the user register. I don't know what I was doing wrong or what I have to do to make this works, please help!

Answer (score 0):

In your forms, don't define meta class and just display the fields like you're doing with the userpassconf. You can even combine the forms into a single form, and then just handle the data in your view like you're already doing, but create two instances. Something like:

```
if request.method == "POST": 
  form = registerUser(request.POST) 
  if form.is_valid(): 
    form_data = form.cleaned_data
    if form_data.get("userpass") == form_data.get("userpassconf"): 
      passmatch = True 
      new_user = userProfile()
      new_user.usermail = form_data.get("usermail")
      new_user.username = form_data.get("username")
      new_user.save()
```

So basically you're just creating an instance of whatever model you want to save to, and assigning the form data to it, and then saving it. And don't forget to import your models into the views file.